# Syntax Query in Python Statement

Tags: python, closures, argument-unpacking

```
[b for _, b in sorted(enumerate(arr, 1), key=lambda x: int.__mul__(*x))]
```

is a list comprehension in Python meant to sort an array in ascending order while using the value at each place multipled by a 1-based index

So [4, 3, 1] would be sorted based on [4*1, 3*2, 1*3] giving [1, 4, 3].

I am trying to understand:
 1. How the _ in the code works
 2. How the *x multiplies the value with its index
(Since the enumerate has 1 as a parameter, I am assuming that is how the 1-based indexing is taken care of).

Comment: `_` is just a regular variable name, intended to hint that the value being stored in it is unused. `int.__mul__(*x)` is a really stupid way of writing `x[0] * x[1]`.

Comment: The code is supposed to multiply each number with its index, not with the next one.

Comment: Yeah, I get it. Doesn’t change the comment.